# Training Data cleaning for Spacy NER

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to train spaCy NER on custom data. Each sample of my training data consists of raw text that is extracted from a documents. Each of my sample contains around 100+ words. For example:

```html
[
  [
    "Some long raw text here \n\n\n This text contains multiple line breaks...",
    {
      "entities": [
        [
          246,
          264,
          "entity_1"
        ...
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

1. My question is, for training NER, I am feeding raw document text to
   the model without any pre-processing. So, does spaCy performs some data pre-processing steps or do I need to perform
   following pre-processing steps on raw data before feeding it to
   spacy:

   - Removal of stop words
   - Removal of punctuation
   - Lower case text
   - Lemmatization
   - Normalization of spaces and line breaks
2. My concern is, in my documents If I have terms like 'Context',
   'Context:', 'context', 'context-1'. and in my model vocabulary, I
   only have word 'Context' then would spaCy treat 'Context:',
   'context' and 'context-1' as OOV word? and will it generates word
   vector of zeros for these words like it does for other OOV words
   before feeding to model?
3. If spaCy perform some pre-processing on training data, what type of pre-processing does it do?
4. Is it possible to log in spaCy what feature vectors gets fed into model for certain sample while training?

Comment: No Pre-processing is require for either training data or test data.

Comment: Assuming that model have vector for word 'apple', then if our training sample contains word 'apple:' (punctuation mark ':' included) will spaCy consider it as OOV and generate word embedding of zeros when feeding it to model for training? Or will it load the embedding for word 'apple'?

Comment: If you train apple as a custom entity it will consider apple on the basis of it's index number otherwise model will ignore "apple:".